# In bash or sh, what is the equivalent of the #include preprocessor directive in C/C++?

Tags: bash, include, sh

In bash or sh, what is the equivalent of the `#include` preprocessor directive in C/C++?

I would like to keep some paths on a separate configuration file, to be loaded by the sh script.

Are there other ways to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `source other_file` or `. other_file`; see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins.

Answer (score 4):

It is `source`.

```
source /path/to/file.sh
```

or even

```
. /path/to/file.sh
```

Comment: Isn't `source` bash-specific (inspired by `csh`)? Taking the question literally, it would be better to use the period.